# Strange text encoding

Tags: java, scala, twitter4j

please excuse my unfamiliarity with Scala/Java. I'm working with an example twitter streaming app. Below is the code:

```
stream.foreachRDD{(rdd, time) =>
   rdd.map(t => {
     Map(
       "user"-> t.getUser.getScreenName,
       "text" -> t.getText,
       "hashtags" -> t.getHashtagEntities.map(_.getText)          
     )
   }).map(_.mkString("\t")).foreach(println)
 }
```

When this prints, I get something like this for hashtags:

```
hashtags -> [Ljava.lang.String;@651a3f4e
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? I'd like to print human-readable hashtags...

Comment: That's the default `toString` implementation. The `[L` means an array of objects iirc.

Comment: and it is an array of java.lang.String

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks !

Comment: @Carcigenicate Apologies, I still can't get the correct implementation. Could you help?

Comment: @Dylan_Larkin `Arrays.toString(t.getHashtagEntities.map(_.getText))`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I already tried that and its complaining about "overloaded method value toString with alternatives..."

Comment: @Dylan_Larkin You might need to add a type annotation so it knows which overload to use.

Comment: @Carcigenicate sooo... this is the part where I'm too unfamiliar with Java...

Comment: `def method1(obj: Any): String = obj match {
    case null => "null"
    case x: Array[AnyRef] => Arrays.toString(x)
    case x: Array[AnyVal] => x.mkString("[",",","]")
    case _ => obj.toString
  }`

method1(t.getHashtagEntities.map(_.getText))

Comment: @Carcigenicate Possible to unmark as duplicate? I feel this answer is somewhat unique to this implementation and I would like to post a proper answer (since I did put in the effort to find it... )

Comment: @Dylan_Larkin You can flag it to have someone look at it. Are you sure it's not a dupe though? The fact that you had to resolve an ambiguous method call doesn't mean that this isn't a dupe.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I’m just saying it wasn’t trivial for me to solve based on the “dupe”. Maybe it’ll be different for others.

Comment: @Dylan_Larkin Again, you can flag the question and state your case.